# Scraping With Curl Post Not Giving Result

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want to scrap this webiste - marcanet.impi.gob.mx/marcanet/controler/RegistroBusca

Below is the code that I am using but I am not getting to the result page.

```
$form_url = "http://marcanet.impi.gob.mx/marcanet/controler/RegistroLista";
$data_to_post = array();
$data_to_post['registro'] = '1384641';
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $form_url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, sizeof($data_to_post));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "fruit=apple; colour=red");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Host: marcanet.impi.gob.mx', 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Referer: http://marcanet.impi.gob.mx/marcanet/controler/RegistroBusca'));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$htm = $dom->load($result);

echo $htm;
```

This is giving me result that the registration number is not found. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean "I want to scrape this website"?

Comment: Yes. I want to scrape this website.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a string as the post body:

```
$data_to_post = 'registro=1384641';
```

Otherwise curl will send it as multipart-form-data.

Also, some of your options don't look right to me and that `Host:` header will get you in trouble if you're not careful. [More info on the options can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).